# Orange3 Windows 10 Edit Plots?

Tags: orange, plotting

In Orange3 64-bit for Windows 10, is it possible to edit plots, graphs, charts, and diagrams interactively?

If not, will this feature be added?

For example, at minimum, I would like to increase the font size of axis labels, and change axis numbers to a consistent format (e.g., instead of 2.5, 3, 3.5, change to 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, etc.).

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://orange.biolab.si/features/interactive-data-visualization/).

Comment: @Media where in that reference does it say anything about altering the axis data, fonts?

Comment: I don't really remember right now, it was long ago. It seems that you yourself have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am [also experiencing](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38242/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-darken-the-axis-of-scatter-plot-in-python-orang) issues with the axis

The only external plot formatting widget seems to be [`color`](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/color.html).

And of course, from within the (scatter) plot there is the obvious option to control things like jitter, data point shape, data point size, data point labels, and values to color by as well as add grid and regression lines.

`Orange` was primarily developed for generating machine learning classifiers, and thus is less concerned about formatting and probably intentionally sparse.

Fortunately, as it's opensource one can always fork/edit source code, or since Orange offers a python script module that allows you to feed your visual data to the the underlying python & orange plot functions.